# Unit testing - Integration/Code gen tools

Tags: java, oracle, unit-testing, mule-studio, emc

I was wondering if any1 came across unit tests on code gen tools. I talk about mulesoft/oracle/tibco/emc etc. where you drag and drop stuff and code is generated(xml formats/somehow).

In such a case, as a developer - 2 questions

1. What is a unit test with codegen tools anyway?
2. In case this is covered as a 'part' of these tools/IDE's - I'm still developing functionality, but a codegen tool only covers the fact that compilation is successful - not really if my unit tests pass. Whats a best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

@dexter31.. i am not sure about codegen tools but for testing your muleflows you can leverage jUnit framework which is in built in anypoint studio..you might want to go through with below link for muleflows unit testing

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Testing